# Problem casting to an interface in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, ria, flex4.5

I am using interfaces for module communication like in [adobe flex documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf64277-7fea.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7d1d). When I have a ModuleLoader in mxml, everything works great.

```
<mx:TabNavigator id="testNav"
                height="100%"
                width="100%">
        <s:ModuleLoader id="firstTab" 
                        label="ONE" 
                        width="100%"
                        url="path/to/module/Mod1.swf"/>

        <s:ModuleLoader id="secondTab"
                        label="TWO" 
                        width="100%"
                        url="path/to/module/Mod2.swf"/>


</mx:TabNavigator>
```

and i have this code

```
var someChild:* = firstTab.child as ISomeModule;
```

ISomeModule is the interface.
But when I have a ModuleLoader in actionscript in another file, when I do the same thing, someChild becomes null when cast to ISomeModule

```
var myLoader:ModuleLoader=new ModuleLoader();
myLoader.percentHeight=50;
myLoader.percentWidth=50;
myLoader.loadModule(moduleURL + "?attr=value&attr2=" + parentDocument.attr2);
```

and in another function, I have

```
var childMod:* = myLoader.child as ISomeModule;
```

`myLoader.child` is not null but when cast to ISomeModule, it becomes null.
Does anyone have an idea about how to solve this? 
thanks

Comment: Are you sure you can cast to an Interface?  Don't you have to cast to an Object?  A variable type can be an interface; but you must use an object that implements that interface at runtime.  Assuming that is wrong. have you tried this: IssomeModule(firstTab.child) ?  Are you sure that firstTab [and child] have valid values?  Could they be null?

Comment: No, firstTab, and child are ok, I tested them and I worked with the functions I declared in ISomeModule, I just did like in the [official documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf64277-7fea.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7d1d)

Comment: Did you take a look at `myLoader.child` in the debugger when you are doing the cast? What type does the debugger show? Does it implement your desired interface?

Comment: Also, when you say the ModuleLoader is "inside a file", is that file itself a Module?  Because it it has its own domain, then its definition for your Interface may not be the same one as the definition where you're doing the cast.

Comment: @Gerhard The problem is that I can't debug this application due to many reasons

Comment: @AmyBlankenship yes, the file is a Module, in this same module I define myLoader and I declare childMod=myLoader.child if that's what you mean

Comment: You need to use the same ApplicationDomain for everything. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776673/communication-between-flex-module-and-application/6776945#6776945

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 things:

- You need the same ApplicationDomain for cross-module class sharing (you should also enable optimizing in your Module compilation): `<s:ModuleLoader url="someURL" applicationDomain="{ApplicationDomain.currentDomain}" />`
- If I remember correctly, it should be `firstChild.content` and not `firstChild.child` for the actual module itself.

Comment: moduleLoader doesn't have the property content

Answer (score 0):

This post is quite some years old but currently I ran into a similar issue by creating ModuleLoader dynamically with AS3.
The above hint to set the ApplicationDomain saved my day... thanks!

```
private function createModule():void {
    _moduleLoader = new ModuleLoader;
    _moduleLoader.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;
    _moduleLoader.addEventListener(ModuleEvent.READY, onModuleReady);
    _moduleLoader.url = "path/to/your/module/MyModule.swf";
    _moduleLoader.loadModule();
}

private function onModuleReady(event:ModuleEvent):void {
    // iMyModule is null if ApplicationDomain is not set
    var iMyModule:* = event.currentTarget.child as IMyModule;
}
```

Thanks,
Olaf