# How to access properties of child of one parent application from from child of another parent application form into the same project? - FLEX

Tags: apache-flex

I have one child say CH_1 of parent application PA_1 and i want to access the properties of that CH_1 from child CH_2 of parent application PA_2 in single flex application.
Hope this question is understandable.

Waiting for reply.

Comment: It's not clear, what are the childs? Explain using an example.

Comment: okey.. I am creating 2 .mxml files say mxml_1 & mxml_2 and 2 module mdl_1 & mdl_2. Now i am assigning mxml_1 as a parent of mdl_1 and mxml_2 as a parent of mdl_2 and i want to access properties of mdl_2 into mdl_1.   HOPE THIS IS WELL THAN BEFORE.

Comment: is this similar? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776673/communication-between-flex-module-and-application